# Magento - Custom validation on forms not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, magento

I'm trying to do form translations for one of my stores.

For this I used the tutorial: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/tag/magento-translation

So I have created my own javascript file and updated local.xml

Each respective code is as follows:

```
if(Validation) {                    
Validation.addAllThese([      
    [
        'welsh-required',                                           
        'Mae\'n rhaid llenwi\'r blwch hwn',   
        function(v,r){ return v.indexOf('valid')==-1?false:true }   
    ],
    [
        'welsh-email',                                              
        'Rhowch gyfeiriad ebost dilys yma.',   
        function(v,r){ return v.indexOf('valid')==-1?false:true }   
    ],
])
}
```

My code for adding this in the head reference in local xml is:

```
<action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/myvalidation.js</name>
</action>
```

An example of trying to use this is the forgot password form. I used the code with the class names I created:

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == 1): ?>
                    <input type="text" name="email" alt="email" id="email_address" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getEmailValue()) ?>" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="text" name="email" alt="email" id="email_address" class="welsh-required required-entry welsh-email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getEmailValue()) ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

The validation does display the new text (but not the two validations together like the original validation). Even if correct data is entered the form wont send.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that condition `if(Validation) {` is not true.
Try wrapping it into `document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {}` condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried this now but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Ok, what browser are you using?
Is your script loaded on page?
Recommend Firefox + Firebug. then you can debug it ;)